# manual query issue on neo4j.ogm using spring boot application

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>NucleiAdmin</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>

 <name>NucleiAdmin</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 <properties>
  <start-class>nuclei.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
    
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>  
  </dependency>

  <!-- spring-data-neo4j -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.RC2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>  

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
    
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
  </dependency> 

  <!-- test scoped beans only -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
   <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>


 <build>
  <finalName>NucleiAdmin</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
   <name>Spring</name>
   <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
  </repository>

  <repository>
   <id>neo4j</id>
   <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>

 </repositories>

 <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

```html
package nuclei.repository;

import java.util.Map;

import nuclei.domain.Blueprint;
import nuclei.domain.IaaSTemplate;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * @author Karthikeyan
 *
 */
@Repository
public interface BlueprintRepository extends GraphRepository<Blueprint>{
 
 @Query("MATCH (Blueprint:Blueprint{isDeleted:'0'}) RETURN id(Blueprint) as id,Blueprint") 
 Iterable<Map<String,Object>> getTemplateBlueprints(); 

 @Query("MATCH (n { name: {0} }) SET n.position = {1}")   
 Blueprint createNewTemplate(String name,String position);
}
```

[image]In my project I am using spring boot,neo4j and org.neo4j.ogm library for integrate neo4j on spring boot. I can able to implement GraphRepository's findone, findall and save methods. But when use my own query for insert a value, it shown an error. I couldn't findout the reason for the Issue. I am using the given query `@Query("CREATE (n:Person { name : 'Andres', title : 'Developer' })")

```html
package nuclei.service;

import java.util.Map;

import nuclei.domain.Blueprint;
import nuclei.domain.IaaSTemplate;
import nuclei.repository.BlueprintRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * @author Karthikeyan
 *
 */
@Service("blueprintService")
public class BlueprintServiceImpl extends GenericService<Blueprint> implements
  BlueprintService {

 @Autowired
 private BlueprintRepository blueprintRepository;

 @Override
 public GraphRepository<Blueprint> getRepository() {
  return blueprintRepository;
 }

 @Override
 public Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getTemplateBlueprints() {
  return blueprintRepository.getTemplateBlueprints();
 }

 @Override
 public Blueprint createNewTemplate(String name,String position){
  return blueprintRepository.createNewTemplate(name,position);
 }
}
```

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/createBp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody BlueprintMessage createBP(
    @FormDataParam("name") String name,
    @FormDataParam("position") String position,
    final HttpServletResponse response) {
   ResponseStatus status = null;
  // Long blueprintId = Long.parseLong(id);
   Blueprint entity = null;
   try {
    entity = blueprintService.createNewTemplate(name, position);
    //entity.setBlueprint(blueprint);
    //entity.setIsDeleted("0");

    super.create(entity);
    status = new ResponseStatus(ResponseStatusCode.STATUS_OK, "SUCCESS");
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return new BlueprintMessage(status, entity);
  }
```

```html
package nuclei.service;

import java.util.Map;

import nuclei.domain.Blueprint;
import nuclei.domain.IaaSTemplate;

/**
 * @author Karthikeyan
 *
 */
public interface BlueprintService extends MainService<Blueprint> {

 Iterable<Map<String, Object>> getTemplateBlueprints();
 
 Blueprint createNewTemplate(String name,String position);
}
```

Comment: You mean you're using SDN? @Query belongs to SDN 4, not the OGM.

Comment: And what's the error, and version of SDN 4?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? dependencies, setup, repository, and how you call it?

Comment: Now i have updated the question, please review the code.

Comment: If you see the error it shows "query() only allows read only cypher. To make modifications use execute()" . Here i want to know how to use the execute().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to SDN 4.0.0.RC2

Previous versions did not allow modifying Cypher statements to be executed via query().

Comment: I am using SDN 4.0.0.M1 only

Comment: M1 is quite old. Please upgrade to 4.0.0.RC2

Comment: once i upgrade the SDN 4.00.RC2 means in shows following error.


java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()

Comment: If you have a dependency on spring data commons, please use version 1.11.0.RC1 for it

Comment: I am using 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.RC2</version>
  </dependency>

and i am  not use any spring data commons.

Comment: Please update your question to add the dependencies you're using. Probably something mismatched there

Comment: Why do you need spring-data-neo4j-rest 3.0.1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87580/discussion-between-luanne-and-faariz-mohammed).

Comment: I removed the spring-data-neo4j-rest but now also it shows same error.
and there is only one spring-data-commons package are used
that was give by 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId> 
<version>4.0.0.RC2</version> 
</dependency>

Comment: I am removed all the dependencies and add updated versions for all the dependency then the error was not showing and the application was running successfully.